# Use a union as a item-type in a tree in order to store two different data types

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Please consider the following code:

```
union tree_item
{
    tree_item(std::valarray<double> const& point)
        : point(point)
    { }
    tree_item(unsigned coord, double coord_value)
        : splitting_line({ coord, coord_value })
    { }

    struct {
        unsigned coord;
        double coord_value;
    } splitting_line;
    std::valarray<double> point;
};
```

How can we make sure, that if a `tree_item` object stores a `point`, the destructor of `point` is called? I could write

```
~tree_item() {
    point.~valarray();
}
```

but I assume, that this leads to undefined behavior, if we had assigned values to `coord` or `coord_value`.

All I want to do, is to use `tree_item` for `T` in

```
template<typename T>
struct tree_node
{
    tree_node(T const& item)
        : item(item)
    { }
    tree_node(T&& item)
        : item(std::move(item))
    { }

    bool is_leaf() const noexcept {
        return !left && !right;
    }

    T item;
    std::shared_ptr<tree_node<T>> left, right;
};
```

`splitting_line` and `point` are the two types of items, that I want to store in the tree. Clearly, I could write a base class and derived classes for `splitting_line` and `point`, respectively. However, since in this case there is no kind of *operation* that I want to perform on these items (I just want to store these different types) and I would need to use `dynamic_cast` or some kind of *type-flag*, this would make my code much too complicated.

So, what should I do?

Comment: If there's no common operation then does it even make sense to store both of these types of items inside the same data structure? I feel like people don't ask themselves this question often enough...

Comment: @Brian Actually, it's important that they're in the same tree.

Comment: I would never use union as C++ class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `union`, you should use a class that handles more of the functionality necessary to have a true variant type: [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
using tree_item = boost::variant<
    splitting_line,
    std::valarray<double>
};
```

The `variant` object will ensure that the correct destructor is called based on whatever is stored. It also keep track of which object it owns, so that you can actually perform type-safe operations on it (something which is also impossible on your `union`).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use boost in this project.

Comment: @0xbadf00d You could still copy how they do it (or find a blog like [this one](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-17/eggs.variant---part-i))

Answer (score 0):

This is what virtual inheritance is for. Use a common base type, maybe called `tree_item_base` with 2 derived types, `tree_item_point` and `tree_item_splitting_line`. `tree_node` will need to use a reference or an auto pointer type, though.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use unrestricted unions in your design, in order to call correct destructor you would have to store information about whats inside your union outside of it, for example inside tree_node or some other kind of wrapper type, which would keep type of data in some enumeration and call correct constructors/destructors.

I have tried your code on gcc/clang with slight modifications and it actually does not emit any warnings with -pedantic.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>  
#include <valarray>

union tree_item
{
    tree_item(std::valarray<double> const& ppoint) : point(ppoint) { 
        //new (&point)std::valarray<double>(ppoint);
    }
    tree_item(unsigned coord, double coord_value)
        : splitting_line({ coord, coord_value })
    { }

    ~tree_item(){
      // cannot call point dtor here because we dont know if it was used
    }

    struct {
        unsigned coord;
        double coord_value;
    } splitting_line;
    std::valarray<double> point;
};

int main() {
    std::valarray<double> point={1,2,3};

    // constructed with std::valarray, destructor must be called manually
    tree_item nn(point);
    std::cout << nn.point[2];
    nn.point.~valarray<double>();

    tree_item nn2(1.0, 2.0);

    return 0;
}
```

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/02f5GI5WTTlLvprY